SSH is trying to reopen a port (for port forwarding) even when not specified
I can start an ssh to a server of mine via:
ssh -L 7777:localhost:7777 other_args...

to do port forwarding. However, if have observed that, if I close the ssh session, and start a new ssh session in the same terminal again, even without specifying the -L flag, it opens the port again. Like if ssh is "remembering" the option I specified before.
In particular, I'm using MSYS2, and I had open two terminals, one to do open and close an ssh session, and another one to execute repeatedly the command netstat -aon | findstr 9797 to see if someone is using the port.
And what I have observed is:
terminal1$ ssh ... # without -L
terminal2$ ...9797 is not open according to netstat... that's nice
terminal2$ inside_ssh$ exit
terminal2$ ...9797 is not open according to netstat... that's nice
terminal1$ ssh -L ...
terminal2$ ... 9797 is open according to netstat... that's nice
terminal1$ inside_ssh$ exit
terminal2$ ... 9797 is not open according to netstat... that's nice
terminal1$ ssh ... # without -L
terminal2$ ... 9797 is OPEN according to netstat... that is NOT NICE

I have even execute ssh with -F none to check if some config might be messing up around but don't.
If I close the terminal entirely and then start a new ssh session without using the -L flag, then 9797 is NOT OPEN again. So it looks like one in a local terminal session I have open a port via port forwarding, ssh remembers to do it again until the end of the local session, regardless of whether -L is specified or not.
Why is that? Is that a particular windows/msys2 thing, is that intended behaviour? Where is "ssh" storing the information that in a previous session the port was open and it must open it again?

SSHv2 supports multiple concurrent sessions per connection, and OpenSSH is sometimes configured to make use of that through its "connection multiplexing" options – ControlMaster, ControlPersist, ControlPath (-S).
For example, if ControlPersist is enabled in your ~/.ssh/config, then closing a shell session will automatically leave the connection still active in background so that it could be used again without re-authenticate, etc., and any "secondary" channels such as port-forwarding will continue to exist during the lifetime of the SSH connection.
Although the secondary channels are not tied to an individual shell session, so they are not "re-opened" but rather should remain open the whole time, which doesn't quite match the symptoms you're describing; but it still seems like the most likely explanation. (Or at the very least, somewhere to start looking for further clues.)
Use ssh somehost -O exit to fully close a background connection for that host. (There is an option to add new forwardings to an existing connection, but AFAIK no option to remove them.)
Use ssh -S none somehost to make a separate non-multiplexed connection.
Use ssh -G somehost to dump the configuration for that host (from ~/.ssh/config); grep the output for ^control to find the relevant settings.

As you say, the connection doesn't remain open, and I barely have any custom config. I have done experiments even with -F none and the result is the same. It is "reopening" the tunnel. I mean, consider that I'm actually using ssh within msys2, which means that I'm under windows. Unless windows have some way to "keep the connection open" in a way that is transparent by the terminal session somehow, and then ssh is just getting it back or whatever weird thing... otherwise it's reopening the session.
